# Animation malfunction

Tags: html, css, animation

With my images, I am having a few malfunctions. Firs of all I had it all working, then I turned one class into five different ones, so I can change their sizes individually without it affecting them all. The only problem is that now that I did that, the pictures are not rotating, just the text is except the first one. Also, when I resize the image to be quite larger which I am going to do it doesn't rotate all the way. At first I thought that it was a problem of the animation, but i am not so sure of that since it is set to rotate at 180 degrees which should happen no matter the size. My website is here http://spencedesign.netau.net/singapore-gallery.html and the way that I want to layout my pictures is [image]

Answer (score 1):

The error in the icons animation is caused because you specified *only* for the `.icon1` element, you have to repeat also for all the other icons:

```
li:hover .icon1, li:hover .icon2, li:hover .icon3, li:hover .icon4, li:hover .icon5, li:hover .label {

  -webkit-transform:translateZ(-32px) rotateY(180deg);

  -webkit-animation-duration:0.33s;
  -webkit-animation-name:rotateOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;

}
```

This is quite an awkward CSS construct though and very hard to mantain, I guess you should give the CSS animation rule based on a general class to every element and another class to each element to pick it individually for your needs, something like this:

```
/* CSS */
.icon-bar li:hover .icon, .icon-bar li:hover .icon-label { 

   your animation code here
}

<!-- HTML -->

<ul class="icon-bar">
<li>
  <span class="icon first-icon"></span>
  <span class="label">item 1</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="icon second-icon"></span>
  <span class="label">item 2</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="icon third-icon"></span>
  <span class="label">item 3</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="icon fourth-icon"></span>
  <span class="label">item 4</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="icon fifth-icon"></span>
  <span class="label">item 5</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

---

> Also, when I resize the image to be quite larger which I am going to do it doesn't rotate all the way. At first I thought that it was a problem of the animation, but i am not so sure of that since it is set to rotate at 180 degrees which should happen no matter the size.

Unfortunately I can't see anything acting like the second part of your question, is there a gallery plugin attached or something? I've tested your webpage with both Chrome Canary and FireFox

Comment: I would give you the check, but if you look now the words are there now for the whole thing. Also I am not sure what you mean by the second part. Sorry, I am a beginner

Comment: I was going through and I realized. In the icon backgrounds CSS it says :nthchild..(2n+2)<--Example So if I just took out the n+2 would that sizing work just for that icon? I tried it out and it seems to work, but I am not sure if I would run into trouble later down the road?

Comment: @user1815176 I saw your page updated, I guess you resolved your issue?  As for the `:nth-child` question, removing `2n` you will get `:nth-child(2)` which means the CSS rule will target the second child of the element yuo append the rule to, so for example:
`li:nth-child(2){ your CSS rules }` will target only the second child element of every `li`. Have a look here for more info http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/